# malloc runs out after looping 100+ times or so

Tags: c, memory-management, malloc

I am reading in a 5045 line csv file 
the most i have been able to load is 100-125 lines before i get the dreaded seg fault 
my last attempt so far has been below

```
    lineholder=malloc(600);
    while(!feof(stdin)){ 


    lineholder=realloc(lineholder,600);
    fgets(lineholder, 600, stdin);//get each line
    if(*lineholder == *en||i==(length-2)){
    break;}
//  printf("past the 102");

        ptrtemp=&arr[i];//initialize ptr

//      printf("past the 105");

        char *s1 = strsep( &lineholder, "," );


        strcpy(ptrtemp->color, s1); 
 //         printf("past the 112");
        tokholder = strsep(&lineholder,d);//gets first token of the line
        strcpy(ptrtemp->director_name, tokholder);

 //     printf("past the 115");
```

now it loops thru the 28 fields fine on taking the input but eventually seg faults like i said around the 100-125 mark 
here is one line of the data for refrence

> Color,Andrew Adamson,284,150,80,82,Kiran Shah,1000,291709845,Adventure|Family|Fantasy,Jim Broadbent,"The Chronicles of Narnia: The Lion, the Witch and the Wardrobe ",286506,1317,Shane Rangi,5,hide and seek|lion|magic|professor|snow,http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0363771/?ref_=fn_tt_tt_1,1463,English,USA,PG,180000000,2005,190,6.9,2.35,0

any suggestions on how to reuse the memory so i don't run out ?
i am so used to java its very hard to comprehend this stuff with c 
thanks

Comment: Do not use `lineholder,` in `strsep( &lineholder, "," )` without first checking the return value of `fgets(lineholder, 600, stdin);`

Comment: Do not use `lineholder,` in `fgets(lineholder, 600, stdin);` without first checking the return value of `lineholder=realloc(lineholder,600);`  Similar issues with `char *s1 = strsep( &lineholder, "," );


        strcpy(ptrtemp->color, s1);`.  Code lacks error checking.

Comment: It just isn't likely to "run out" after processing 125 lines of text.  Much more likely is that your code corrupted the heap.  Those strcpy() calls are loaded weapons when you don't check how much they copy.

Comment: Every single library function call should check for error conditions (read the manual!). Compile with all warnings (including extra warnings). Use valgrind to find memory misuses and debug with gdb to find the specific failure point.

Comment: i have used gdb and the seg happens at the 221 record and the realloc returns a null pointer  and segs                                                                            lineholder=realloc(lineholder,600);     this at the 221 line read in returns a null and of course crashes  and yes i am missing some check but they would crash it anyways just trying to get this working and understand why its happing

Comment: "yes i am missing some check" --> save time.  Add the checks and  [@max](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46530146/malloc-runs-out-after-looping-100-times-or-so#comment80015854_46530146) good advice.  Or leave the checks out and take longer to debug.